# Problem with resizing partition in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, disk-usage, gnu, parted, size

I have enlarged my partition with GNU Parted but when checking with df -h and (parted) print I see that the sizes are different. How can I make df -h reflect the actual size of the partition? Thank you very much in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably grew the partition with its filesystem mounted, it being your root drive. It looks like a cloud environment, so I guess you might not have an option to do it from e.g. live media.

The ext4 filesystem supports online growing its size, try the following command:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1
```

The default action of resize2fs is to grow the partition into any unused space.

Please note, that resizing partitions and filesystems while mounted can generally be quite dangerous, and especially resizing partitions can lead to complete data loss. Generally i'd say, growing partitions into unallocated space is safe.

See also the following related question:

https://serverfault.com/questions/509468/how-to-extend-an-ext4-partition-and-filesystem

Comment: Thank you Henrik Juul Pedersen, it works fine!